# How to deal with Jenkins error "Library ***expected to contain at least one of src or vars directories"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Working on my 6th or 7th Jenkins script now - and I already noticed they share a bit of code (essentially just the same groovy subroutines over and over again). I wouldn't like to continue with that and rather learn some best practices.
It seems that "[Shared Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)" are the thing to do. (Or is there a better way when you just want to share groovy code, not script steps etc.?)

Those scripts are part of a larger repo (that contains the source of the entire project, including the other scripts), stored in a subfolder `Jenkins/Library` with this structure:

```
Jenkins/Library
+- vars
|  common_code.groovy
```

There is only a `vars` folder, no  `src`. The documentation said

> For Shared Libraries which only define Global Variables (vars/), or a Jenkinsfile which only needs a Global Variable, the annotation pattern @Library('my-shared-library') _ may be useful for keeping code concise. In essence, instead of annotating an unnecessary import statement, the symbol _ is annotated.

so I concluded that I wouldn't need a `src` folder and can do with `vars` alone.

The library is made available via "Configure Jenkins" > "Global Pipeline Libraries" with SourcePath set to "`/Jenkins/Library/`" and is brought in with the statement `@Library('{name}') _`  as first line of the script.

However, when attempting to use the library, I get the error shown in the subject.
What's the problem?  (I already searched around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314373/jenkins-throw-error-library-expected-to-contain-at-least-one-of-src-or-vars-dir) instance of the problem, but that doesn't seem to fit for my issue - unless I misunderstood something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify a name of the library you should set the same name in your jenkins settings:

> **Name**.
> An identifier you pick for this library, to be used in the @Library
> annotation. An environment variable library.THIS_NAME.version will
> also be set to the version loaded for a build (whether that comes from
> the Default version here, or from an annotation after the @
> separator).

Your `'{name}'` parameter inside of `@Library()` means you should add a library with the same name. Because it's not a variable like `"${name}"` which is not a built in variable and undefined.

If you wish to set up your library with the same name as your jenkins pipleine you could use `env.JOB_NAME` variable, or check the all environment and pre-defined variables:

```
println env.getEnvironment()
```

Or check job parameters only:

```
println params
```

Now step-by-step instructions:

1. Create your library, for example from Git SCM as [shown on the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnGbh.jpg).
2. Put your library code to the project, e.g: `<project_root_folder>/vars/common_code.groovy`. You don't need your additional path `Jenkins/Library`. Also you have named your file in 'snake case' style, which is [not usual for groovy](https://hrmpw.github.io/jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/):

> The **vars** directory hosts scripts that define global variables
> accessible from Pipeline. The basename of each *.groovy file should be
> a Groovy (~ Java) identifier, conventionally `camelCased`.

So your file in **'camel case'** should looks `CommonCode.groovy`.

3. Write your library code:

```
// vars/commonCode.groovy

// Define your method
def call() {
   // do some stuff
   return 'Some message'
}
```

4. Write your pipeline. Example of scripted pipeline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

// yourPipeline.groovy file in your project

@Library('jenkins-shared-library') _

// Get the message from the method in your library
def messageText = commonCode() as String
println messageText
```

If you wish to define some global variables [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205761/how-can-i-define-a-global-variable-or-constant-using-jenkins-pipeline-shared-lib) also may help you.

**PS:** Using 'vars' folder allows you to load everything from your **vars** folder once at the same time. If you wish to load dynamically use import from **src** folder.